# Creating a dynamic array of a structure element then creating a dynamic array of the structure. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, nested

I am attempting to create a structure of students, then inside that structure there is an array of grades (or marks) based on the user input of how marks.

I then am attempting to create a dynamic array of the Student structure.

I want to interact with these pointers ie, Input student info and grades then cout them however i dont think i am doing this properly. Here is a segment of the beginning of my code. My main problem is creating an array of marks, I cant find in my textbook how to declare it.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


struct Student
{
  string name;
  int id;
  int* mark;
  ~Student()
 {
   delete [] mark;
   mark = NULL;
 };
};

void initStudent(Student* ptr, int markNum, int studentNum );   // function prototype for initialization
void sayStudent(Student* ptr, int markNum, int studentNum);     // function prototype for printing

//*********************** Main Function ************************//
int main ()
{
  int marks, studentNum;
  Student stu;           // instantiating an STUDENT object
  Student*  stuPtr = &stu;  // defining a pointer for the object
  cout << "How many marks are there? ";
  cin >>  marks;
  cout << "How many students are there?";
  cin >> studentNum;
  Student* mark = new int[marks];
  Student* students = new Student[studentNum];

  initStudent(students,marks,studentNum);      // initializing the object
  sayStudent(students,marks,studentNum);       // printing the object
  delete [] students;

return 0;

} // end main

//-----------------Start of functions----------------------------//

void initStudent(Student* ptr, int markNum, int studentNum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < studentNum; i++)
    {

       cout << "Enter Student " << i+1 << " Name :";
       cin >> ptr[i].name;
       cout << "Enter Student ID Number :";
       cin >> ptr[i].id;
       for (int j = 0; j < markNum; j++)
        {
       cout << "Please enter a mark :";
       cin >> ptr[i].mark[j];
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: *I cant find in my textbook how to declare it.* -- `std::vector<int>` `std::vector<Student>` -- Get another text book.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I need to dynamically allocate memory. Not just create a vector.

Comment: @RoyGunderson _"I need to dynamically allocate memory."_ What do you think a `std::vector` does actually?

Comment: Rather than `initStudent` may i suggest a constructor in `Student`?

Comment: @RoyGunderson *I then am attempting to create a **dynamic array** of the Student structure* -- The dynamic array in C++ is `std::vector`.

Comment: @RoyGunderson [What your textbook doesn't show you](http://ideone.com/hMobri)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the `marks` array in each `Student` element.

```
Student* students = new Student[studentNum];
for (int i = 0; i < studentNum; i++) {
    students[i].mark = new int[marks];
}
```

You could also do it in `initStudent`.

```
void initStudent(Student* ptr, int markNum, int studentNum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < studentNum; i++)
    {

       cout << "Enter Student " << i+1 << " Name :";
       cin >> ptr[i].name;
       cout << "Enter Student ID Number :";
       cin >> ptr[i].id;
       ptr[i].mark = new int[markNum]
       for (int j = 0; j < markNum; j++)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a mark :";
            cin >> ptr[i].mark[j];
        }
     }
  }
```